# OpenMP parallel computation doesn't creates new threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the code like this

```
double ***arrayInit(int nz, int nx, int ny) {
  double ***u3d;
  u3d = new double **[nz];
  for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++) {
    u3d[k] = new double *[nx];
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
      u3d[k][i] = new double[ny];
      for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j)
        u3d[k][i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  return u3d;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size(0);
    int rank = 0;

    Coefficients coefs; //structure with some coefficients for calculation
    map<string, string> config;


   coefs = fillCoefficients(config);


    auto rho0niz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto T0niz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto p0niz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);

        for (int k = 0; k < coefs.H1p1; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < coefs.Lp1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < coefs.Mp1; ++j) {
                rho0niz[k][i][j] =
                    pow(1.0 - coefs.Lh * (k - 1 + 1) * coefs.h, coefs.nu - 1);
                T0niz[k][i][j] =
                    1.0 - coefs.Lh * (k - 1 + 1) * coefs.h; //Степень +1 к индексу
                p0niz[k][i][j] = rho0niz[k][i][j] * T0niz[k][i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    auto u0niz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto v0niz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto w0niz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);

    auto rhoniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto uniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto vniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto wniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto Tniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto pniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);


    auto rhotniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto utniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto vtniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto wtniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto Ttniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);
    auto ptniz = arrayInit(coefs.H1p1, coefs.Lp1, coefs.Mp1);



    for (int k = 0; k < coefs.H1p1; ++k)
        for (int i = 0; i < coefs.Lp1; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < coefs.Mp1; ++j) {
                rhoniz[k][i][j] = rho0niz[k][i][j];
                uniz[k][i][j] = u0niz[k][i][j];
                vniz[k][i][j] = v0niz[k][i][j];
                wniz[k][i][j] = w0niz[k][i][j];
                Tniz[k][i][j] = T0niz[k][i][j];
                pniz[k][i][j] = rho0niz[k][i][j] * T0niz[k][i][j];

                rhotniz[k][i][j] = rho0niz[k][i][j];
                utniz[k][i][j] = u0niz[k][i][j];
                vtniz[k][i][j] = v0niz[k][i][j];
                wtniz[k][i][j] = w0niz[k][i][j];
                Ttniz[k][i][j] = T0niz[k][i][j];
                ptniz[k][i][j] = rho0niz[k][i][j] * T0niz[k][i][j];
            }

    double rd = 0;

    int timestamp_count = 10000;


    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

    double utniz_res = -1, vtniz_res = -1, wtniz_res = -1, rhotniz_res = -1, Ttniz_res = -1;

    for (int n = 1; n <= timestamp_count; ++n) 
    {
        cout << "=============================== n " << n << endl;

#pragma omp parallel for private(utniz_res, vtniz_res, wtniz_res, rhotniz_res,Ttniz_res)
        for (int k = 1; k < coefs.H1; ++k) {
            utniz_res = -1;
            vtniz_res = -1;
            wtniz_res = -1;
            rhotniz_res = -1;
            Ttniz_res = -1;
            for (int i = 1; i < coefs.L; ++i) 
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < coefs.M; ++j) 
                {

                    utniz_res = f_u(coefs, uniz, tniz,rhoniz,vniz,wniw,pniz);
                    vtniz_res = f_v(coefs, uniz, tniz,rhoniz,vniz,wniw,pniz);
                    wtniz_res = f_w(coefs, uniz, tniz,rhoniz,vniz,wniw,pniz);
                    rhotniz_res = f_rho(coefs, uniz, tniz,rhoniz,vniz,wniw,pniz);;
                    Ttniz_res =  f_t(coefs, uniz, tniz,rhoniz,vniz,wniw,pniz);
#pragma omp critical 
                        {
                            utniz[k][i][j] = utniz_res;
                            vtniz[k][i][j] = vtniz_res;
                            wtniz[k][i][j] = wtniz_res;
                            rhotniz[k][i][j] = rhotniz_res;
                            Ttniz[k][i][j] = Ttniz_res;
                        }

                }
            }

        }


    return 0;
}
```

But omp parallel doesn't create any aditional threads. What I'm doing wrong?
When I look on count of thread I see 1 value. 
Function for calculating depends on previous data resutls that are stored in additional set of arrays.

The main question: how I should define pragme omp parallel for to use dynamic arrays for computation. E.G each arrays should be 50x400x40.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with you using dynamic arrays. It has to do with how you've set up OpenMP for this program. What is the line you are using to compile the program?

Comment: Side note: you don't need a `critical` section around your code as you have. Each of your threads will be accessing separate portions of the arrays (because they are split up according to `k`), and so will never attempt to edit the same locations in memory. Remove that `pragma` and you'll speed up your code substantially!

Comment: Thanks for you note! And yes, OpenMP support was disabled in my VS project and I don't know why